Sequelize findAndCountAll with literal count and having clause and subquery getting column not found on subquery column for count,
Sequelize findAndCountAll with having clause and subquery getting column not found on subquery column for count,
tried subQuery:false and  subQuery:true but not worked,
tried with finAll but i need all count also,
so with findAllAndCOunt used but not worked

Please elaborate: what model definition you have and what count you're trying to get
